# Why is sculpting causing trouble with object?

Tags: sculpting

Here I am sculpting in sculpt mode [image]

But for some reason when I go to object mode, the object starts to stretch some parts-[image]
This is how it looks in edit mode-[image]

If anyone could help, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem... I am using a multi resolution modifier and had it turned on to only 1 (preview). When I change the preview to 2 everything is back to normal!

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to the shading in different mode. I suggest to switch to sculpt mode and smooth out these areas and then come back to object mode.

You can also have a look at these areas in edit mode and you will see if there are distortions.

Comment: It doesn't show anything in edit mode, and when I try to smooth it out, nothing really changes in object mode...

Comment: When I look at the image you posted in edit mode I can see N-Gons, get rid of this. If you don't know how to avoid n-Gons search here for this topic, it's a common topic.